# Helm package unable to be installed from charts stable

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install memcached from helm charts stable repo

My `requirements.yaml` file looks like this

```
- name: stable/memcached
  repository: https://charts.helm.sh/stable
  version: 2.7.1
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: stable/rabbitmq chart not found in repo https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```

I tried this on my computer

```
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
helm search memcached --versions | grep 2.7.1
```

and I can see

```
stable/memcached    2.7.1           1.5.12          Free & open source, high-performance, distributed memory ...
```

Can someone advice why I am seeing this error?

Answer (score 1):

I have just replaced the chart name in my `requirements.yaml` file

```
- name: memcached
  repository: https://charts.helm.sh/stable
  version: 2.7.1
```